# Is there some way I can achieve the distributive property for arrays in `jq`?

Tags: arrays, json, operators, jq, cartesian-product

I want to multiply 2 arrays to produce a mixed reduce.  I compare this to using the FOIL method expanding and distributing parenthesized terms between polynomials into a resulting, combined expression in algebra.

I was hoping to avoid having to write a `foreach` loop, even if it automatically works for any array length, and doing that for every array mixture I want to create.

I also want to avoid creating some resultant array through iterating the first array, combining the terms from the second array, and then somehow performing a total composition in this filter segment, possibly requiring a `flatten` directive at the end.  This seems like too many steps for what I need, and could be more concisely represented.  A `*` operator perhaps?

I'm starting to think the second method is what I need to do since I may not want to 'multiply' the terms, but instead create a new array or object to use while working with the rest of my task.

My question is starting to sound like essentially asking how to enter a double `foreach` loop in `jq` using filters and only the data elements, not that actual `foreach` loop?

In my example I essentially want to use 2 arrays, each containing a pair of terms to be used in an enumeration of states, to create a resulting array that allows me to iterate through 4 total cases.  This is similar to how combinations are calculated.

Does anybody know what I am talking about? :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're interested in outer-products.  In any case, here is a definition of `outer/2` for forming an outer-product of two arrays:

```
def outer(a; b): [a[] as $x | b[] as $y | [$x, $y]];
```

Example:

```
outer([1,2]; [3,4])
```

yields:

```
 [[[1,3],[1,4]],[[2,3],[2,4]]]
```

#### outer(a;b;f)

You might want to use this variant (which is similar to outer(A, B, f) in R, for example):

```
def outer(a; b; f):
  [a[] as $x | b[] as $y | [$x, $y] | f];
```

For example:

```
def times: reduce .[] as $x (1;.*$x);

outer([1,2];[3,4]; times)
```

yields the ordinary outer-product:

```
[[3,4],[6,8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the implicit cartesian product formed when using multiple `[]` iterators will help you express your problem.  For example, the following filter computes the product of `a1` and `a2` without explicit loops:

```
def a1: [1,2];
def a2: [3,4];  
[ a1[] * a2[] ] | add
```

giving the result `21`.  Using string interpolation shows the operations more clearly.  With the above `a1` and `a2`

```
[ "(\(a1[]) * \(a2[]))" ] | join("+")
```

produces

```
(1 * 3)+(2 * 3)+(1 * 4)+(2 * 4)
```

You can also form a collection of objects with object constructors. E.g.

```
[ {x:a1[], y:a2[]} ]
```

produces

```
[
  { "x": 1, "y": 3 },
  { "x": 1, "y": 4 },
  { "x": 2, "y": 3 },
  { "x": 2, "y": 4 }
]
```

with this approach you will need to decide how the objects should be combined.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a weirdly-timed morning epiphany that I just tried and gives me an acceptable result.

I see there are other answers already, and I will probably accept one of those based solely on the content since they seem to be more concise and descriptive, especially with math and programming background.  I wish I could accept more than one!

I will still add my `jq` expression into the mix as it does display slightly different terms, that may represent the algorithm I wanted but did not know clearly earlier, and does so in a complete `jq` command invocation:

```
⋊> ~ jq -cn '["one", "two"] as $num | ["a", "b"] as $let | [($num[] | [.]) + ($let[] | [.])]'                                                                                                       10:01:42
[["one","a"],["two","a"],["one","b"],["two","b"]]
```

Comment: `outer( ["one", "two"]; ["a", "b"])` produces the FOIL result you said you wanted: `[["one","a"],["one","b"],["two","a"],["two","b"]]`